# How does one supply a gradient (or hessian) to nlm?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, model-fitting

In the helpfile for the non linear minimiser function `stats::nlm` it states that one of the arguments `f` is (emphasis mine):

> the function to be minimized, returning a single numeric value. This should be a function with first argument a vector of the length of p followed by any other arguments specified by the ... argument.
>   **If the function value has an attribute called gradient or both gradient and hessian attributes**, these will be used in the calculation of updated parameter values.

Does this mean that gradients and hessians are supplied by a command like:

```
attr(f, 'gradient') <- function(...){...}
```

What should the input and outputs of this function be?

Contrast this to the general optimiser `stats::optim`:

```
optim(par, fn, gr = NULL, ...,
  method = c("Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN",
             "Brent"), ...)
```

where the gradient is explicitly specified as an argument to `optim`, as an example of this see: [how to propery specify a gradient function for use in optim() or other optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622956/how-to-propery-specify-a-gradient-function-for-use-in-optim-or-other-optimizer)

Examining the code internals of `nlm` did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple one-dimensional example:

```
f <- function(x) {
  out <- -exp(-0.5 * x^2)
  attr(out, 'gradient') <- -x * out 
  attr(out, 'hessian') <-  (x^2 - 1) * out
  return(out)
}

nlm(f, 1.3, hessian = TRUE, check.analyticals = TRUE)
```

Which gives:

```
# $minimum
# [1] -1
# 
# $estimate
# [1] 4.23687e-14
# 
# $gradient
# [1] 4.23687e-14
# 
# $hessian
# [,1]
# [1,]    1
# 
# $code
# [1] 1
# 
# $iterations
# [1] 3
```